# Redirect the output of kestrel's console to richtextbox

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

well i have an api running on Kestrel server locally,i needed to run it without showing the console so i used the vbs answer from [superuser](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/redirect-the-output-of-kestrel-to-a-file) and it worked, now my problem is that i want to stream out the messages that were shown on console to somewhere else like a file or richtextbox of windowsform ,if there is any why ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the Kestrel's output to a local file, then you can watch the file changes.

Example to redirect the Kestrel output:
`dotnet run > d:\kestrel-output.txt`

Here is a code snip to watch a text file's changes. This approach uses time interval but you can try the [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0).

```
...
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Load += (s, e) =>
        {
            const string targetFile = @"d:\kestrel-output.txt";
            _ = WatchTextFileAsync(targetFile,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
                change =>
                {
                    Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(change);
                            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                        })
                    );
                },
                cancellationTokenSource.Token
            );
        };

        Closing += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!e.Cancel)
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        };
    }

    public async Task WatchTextFileAsync(
        string path,
        TimeSpan checkInterval,
        Action<string> onChange,
        CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        fs.Seek(fs.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin); //ignore current content
        var sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (fs.Position > fs.Length) //new file? replaced? if so read from the beginning
                {
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

                if (fs.Position < fs.Length) //check offset
                {
                    var change = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    onChange?.Invoke(change);
                }

                await Task.Delay(checkInterval, token);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            sr.Dispose();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: pretty much what i'm locking for instead i gonna read the log file.   Thank you so much sir

Comment: @OMAR this is other approach, however, the code will also work to retrieve the log file content.